# how to blur effect in real view cocos2dx like ios blur effact

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

[image]I have use RENDER TEXTURE blur effect but it is not proper blur. This is not real time view, I want real time blur effect like ios given effect.

I have use [this tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/User_Tutorial-RenderTexture_Plus_Blur) now what i want to achieve is when there is something (some animation)is running behind image i want to see some blur effects (dynamically). the link gives static blur image.

Comment: could you share some pictures of what you want to achieve?